# findstr, match row contaning x or z but not y in x with regex

Tags: regex, cmd, findstr

Consider a large log file containing data; the goal is to capture all rows containing either `(TRxxxx)`, where the x's can be anything from 0000 to 9999, and also capture all rows containing "`error`".
I have to do this using the cmd, so I have tried to apply `findstr`.

One issue I have run into is that sometimes there are successful runs stating (TRxxxx), such as: "`(TR1234) Power '60 KB' has been deployed to version '9'`". I do not want these, only the ones that have failed.

I considered using regex to match everything containing "`(TRxxxx)`" or "`error`", but not "`(TRxxxx) the deployment has been successful`".

I tried to do this using the following: `findstr /R "^((?!has been deployed).*$)|.*error.*|\(TR[0-9]{4}.*\)" test.log` but it still captures "has been deployed", and I think overall it's a broken mess.

Test input to make it easier to work with:

```
(TR3919) Power '1' has been deployed to version '1'       <-- no match
(TR9102) Power '2' has NOT been deployed to version '2'   <-- match
Random text and l3773r5, with a big error...              <-- match
(TR1337) complicated                                      <-- match
(TR1239) error                                            <-- match
```

Comment: `findstr` does not support regex, these are just patterns that are similar to regex. You can't use lookarounds there.

Comment: Oof, that explains a lot, thanks!

Comment: See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868), it might help. Or, just use Powershell instead.

Comment: What about this: `findstr "(TR[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) error" "test.log" | findstr /V /C:"has been deployed"`

Comment: Thanks, aschipfl, your suggestion worked! Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered.